# FlatList is not rendering my data inside react-native-tab-view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, frontend, react-native-flatlist, react-native-tab-view

I have a state `this.state.mantras` which gets updated everytime I post a new `mantra`.

I have a component with a FlatList to render each of the mantras. However, the FlatList is not rendering anything. I am able to console.log the state which logs the updated state of the mantras array every time.

I have a feeling that it's caused by something to do with react-native-tab-view within which I am trying to render the flatlist.

```
SecondRoute = () => (
    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      numColumns={1}
      data={this.state.mantras}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
    />
)

render() {
 console.log(this.state) <-- success
  return (
   <TabView
    renderTabBar={props =>
      <TabBar
        bounces
        {...props}
        style={styles.tabStyle}
      />
    }
    navigationState={this.state}
    renderScene={SceneMap({
      second: this.SecondRoute, <--- fails to render, no errors
    })}
    onIndexChange={index => this.setState({ index })}
    initialLayout={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width }}
   />
  )
 }

_renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
  <View>
   <View style={styles.mantraCard} key={item.id}>
   <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
   <Text style={styles.description}>{item.description}</Text>
   </View>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: When I remove  the <TabView> wrapper and just add the SecondRoute component as is, it renders successfully

Comment: try warpping <FlatList>  with a <View> , if it doesn't work , try adding extraData={this.state} in FlatList, may help u

Comment: @OzgeCokyasar did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @OzgeCokyasar did you find any solution to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

last month, I met the problem when react-native-scrollable-tab-view. the reason is the flatList no height in tab view on android platform. but on ios, it works well. so we have two solutions.

1. give the tabView a height

   ```
      <ScrollableTabView
      style={{ height: 300 }
       initialPage={0}                    
       }
     >
     // you list view
    </ScrollableTabView>
   ```

   2, I modify the scrollTabView, made it same with ios, which use animated.ScrollView

   ```
    renderScrollableContent() {
   {
   const scenes = this._composeScenes();
   return <Animated.ScrollView
   horizontal
   pagingEnabled
   automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
   contentOffset={{ x: this.props.initialPage * this.state.containerWidth, 
   }}
   ref={(scrollView) => { this.scrollView = scrollView; }}
   onScroll={Animated.event(
     [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: this.state.scrollXIOS, }, }, }, 
   ],
     { useNativeDriver: true, listener: this._onScroll, }
   )}
   onMomentumScrollBegin={this._onMomentumScrollBeginAndEnd}
   onMomentumScrollEnd={this._onMomentumScrollBeginAndEnd}
   scrollEventThrottle={16}
   scrollsToTop={false}
   showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
   scrollEnabled={!this.props.locked}
   directionalLockEnabled
   alwaysBounceVertical={false}
   keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
   {...this.props.contentProps}
   >
     {scenes}
   </Animated.ScrollView>;
   ```

   }